# Save record in a pageblock table on custom object

Tags: visualforce

If the checkbox is true, the class checkTime will check if the time inputted in the picklist is already taken. 
When I click the checkbox, nothing seems to happen and there's that comma(,) below. 
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

### Controller

```
public with sharing class wrapper_test_controller {

    public List<SelectOption> getStud() {
      List<SelectOption> myStud = new List<SelectOption>();
          for(student__c getEm : [select Id, First_Name__c, name from Student__c]) {
              myStud.add(new SelectOption(getEm.Id, getEm.Name+','+ ' ' + getEm.first_name__c));
              }

      return myStud;      
    }


    public list<sched> schedules{get;set;}

     public wrapper_test_controller(){
     schedules = new List<sched>();

    list<teacher__c> object1 = [select id,name, First_name__c, Subject__c, Room_assignment__c from teacher__c ];

    list<schedule__c> object2 = [Select id, name, teacher__c, time__c, student__c, parent__c from schedule__c ];

    for(teacher__c teacher : object1){
        schedules.add(new sched(teacher));
    }
    for (schedule__c oras: object2){
        schedules.add(new sched(oras));
    }

}
public class sched{
    public Id tid {get;set;}
    public Id sid {get;set;}
    public Name sname {get;set;}
    public string steacher{get;set;}
    public string tlname{get;set;}
    public string tfname{get;set;}
    public string sparent{get;set;}
    public string sstudent{get;set;}
    public string oras{get;set;}
    public string room{get;set;}
    public string tsubject{get;set;}
    public string chkbx{get;set;}

public sched(teacher__c object1){
this.tid = object1.id;
this.tlname = object1.name;
this.tfname = object1.first_name__c;
this.tsubject = object1.subject__c;
this.room = object1.room_assignment__c;
}
public sched(schedule__c object2){

this.sid = object2.id;
this.steacher = object2.teacher__c;
this.oras= object2.time__c;
this.sstudent =object2.student__c;
this.sparent =object2.parent__c;

}
}
public PageReference checkTime() {
        return null;
    }


public class checkTime {
    public list<schedTime> schedule{get;set;}

    checkTime () {
        String teacher1 = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('teacher');
        String tim1 = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('time1');
        List<schedule__c> object2 = [Select id, name, teacher__c, time__c, student__c, parent__c from schedule__c WHERE teacher__c = :teacher1  AND time__c = :tim1 ];
        List<schedTime> schedules = new List<schedTime>();
        for (schedule__c time1: object2){
            schedules.add(new schedTime(time1));
        }
        if(schedules.size() > 0){
           apexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(Apexpages.severity.error, 
           'Please select another time. this  time already taken.'));}

           else{
           apexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(Apexpages.severity.error, 
           'Time.'));



      }
    }
}


   public class schedTime{
        public Id tid {get;set;}
        public string teacher {get;set;}



       public schedTime(schedule__c schedule){

            this.tid = schedule.id;
            this.teacher = schedule.teacher__c;
        }
    }


public class save{
}
}
```

### VFP

```
             <strong>   Welcome  {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}!
                <apex:outputLabel style="float:right" > Date: {!MONTH(TODAY())}/ {!DAY(TODAY())}/ {!YEAR(TODAY())} </apex:outputLabel>
             </strong>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
     <apex:outputText >Select Student:</apex:outputText>
            <apex:selectList size="1" >
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Stud}" />
            </apex:selectList>
     <apex:pageblocktable value="{!schedules}" var="schedule">
      <apex:column headerValue="Teacher"  id="teacher" value=" {!schedule.tlname}, {!schedule.tfname}" />
      <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!schedule.tsubject}"/>
      <apex:column headerValue="Room Assignment" value="{!schedule.room}"/>
      <apex:column headerValue="Time" id="time1" >
      <apex:selectList value="{!schedule.oras}" multiselect="false" size="1">
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="9:00 AM" itemLabel="9:00 AM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="10:00 AM" itemLabel="10:00 AM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="11:00 AM" itemLabel="11:00 AM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="1:00 PM" itemLabel="1:00 PM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="2:00 PM" itemLabel="2:00 PM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="3:00 PM" itemLabel="3:00 PM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="4:00 PM" itemLabel="4:00 PM"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemValue="5:00 PM" itemLabel="5:00 PM"/>
      </apex:selectList>  
      </apex:column>
      <apex:column headerValue="Check Time" >
          <apex:inputCheckbox id="chkbx" value="{!schedule.oras}" >
              <apex:actionSupport event="onClick" ACtion="{!checkTime}" reRender="chkbx"/>

           </apex:inputCheckbox>
         </apex:column>

      </apex:pageblocktable>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!checkTime}" value="Proceed to next STUDENT"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!checkTime}" value="Next"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
     <br/>       
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

[image]

Comment: Gelay I didn't get you issue

Comment: Need more details about the issue. @gelay

Comment: the user will choose on the pcklist if what time he wishes to schedule a meeting. if the checkbox on the right side is checked, and the schedule is already taken, a text will appear that the time is already taken and he should choose another time.

Comment: @gelay then on click of checkTime you need to call controller method and check there if you are conditions there.

Comment: when i click the checkbox, nothing happens. whats wrong with the code?

Comment: @gelay you want to call controller method on click on check box?

Comment: yes. and it will return an error if the time selected is already taken.